# How can I visually compare refactoring options?

Tags: d3.js, diff, visualization, force-layout, directed-graph

I have an existing system model, representing services calling APIs backed by one or more implementations in perhaps other services, in the form of a DAG. I've been rendering this by [GraphViz dot files' digraph](http://www.graphviz.org/Documentation/dotguide.pdf) which is fairly reasonable, if sometimes difficult to enforce layering.

[image: Diagram of service and API dependencies]

While considering various possible refactorings of services and APIs, I'd like to be able to chart alternative routes towards an end goal. Each refactoring step would yield a different DAG – represented in terms of diffs from the previous DAG (e.g., convert service *A*'s use of API *x* in service *B* to API *y* in service *C*) – and similarly renderable.

What tools are there to be able to create such "refactoring paths" and then visualize flows between them, determine dependencies and parallelism? Extra bonus points for goal seeking (e.g., no dependencies from any service other than service *A* on service *C*; cheapest path based on weights) and providing a loose ordering of refactorings that demonstrate their (presumably) monotonically increasing system value.

I am picturing two UI components:

1. a DAG diff that shows visually the nodes/vectors that got replaced in the source graph with nodes/vectors in the second
2. a controlling display that acts like [D3](https://mbostock.github.com/d3/)'s [force layout](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout) that lets you navigate the loosely connected DAG of refactorings and select which refactoring you'd like to see the before/after picture in the DAG diff.

That said, I'm totally up to other tooling, formats, etc. Just would like to be able to produce these and display them to other people as to why what we're doing is valuable (goal assertion) and taking as long as it does (dependencies and Gantt charts).

Answer (score 1):

Would it be feasible for you to create a separate tool that, given two similar DAGs, outputs the "merge" of them? If that's possible, then visualizing the merge DAG will probably tell you a lot about both DAGs. You can color-code the nodes by whether they appear in both DAGs or in either.

That's how we originally designed the visual diffs of workflow graphs in VisTrails, [see here](http://www.vistrails.org/index.php/File:Visual_diff_composite.png).

If you insist on showing the two DAGs side by side, creating the merge DAG might *still* be the right idea, because then dot can lay the merge graph out, and you can simply hide the appropriate nodes for each subgraph. In this way, the shared structure will be laid out consistently by construction.

Comment: Yes, I can. Since the before and after DAGs are just diffs applied, I know what nodes are identical in each. Now I just have to figure out how to, for a set of not-entirely-orthogonal diffs, build the traversal DAG of DAGs.